# Trouble getting images to line up in divs with different lengths of content

Tags: html, css

My apples line up fine when the text underneath is all the same height (on one line). But in the my second line of apples, when I put text underneath that goes on to two lines or more, the apple jumps up. How do I get the apples to line up even when the text below is different heights.

See my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S9XR6/2/

```
                <div id="wrapper-icons">
                <div class="icons_row">
                    <div class="icons_cell1">
                        <img alt="" height="106" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="106" />
                        <p class="rtecenter">Name 1<br />
                            Title 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons_cell2">
                        <img alt="" height="106" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="106" />
                        <p class="rtecenter">Name 2<br />
                            Title 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons_cell3">
                        <img alt="" height="106" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="106" />
                        <p class="rtecenter">Name 3<br />
                            Title 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons_cell4">
                        <img alt="" height="106" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="106" />
                        <p class="rtecenter">Name 4<br />
                            Title 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="wrapper-icons">
                <div class="icons_row">
                    <div class="icons_cell1">
                        <img alt="" height="106" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="106" />
                        <p class="rtecenter">Name 1<br />
                            Senior VP / Chief Information Officer</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons_cell2">
                        <img alt="" height="106" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="106" />
                        <p class="rtecenter">Name 2<br />
                            Title 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons_cell3">
                        <img alt="" height="106" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="106" />
                        <p class="rtecenter">Name 3<br />
                            Title 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icons_cell4">
                        <img alt="" height="106" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Honeycrisp-Apple.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" width="106" />
                        <p class="rtecenter">Name 4<br />
                            Title 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

#wrapper-icons {
position:relative;
width:100%;
border: none;
margin: 35px 0 0 0;
```

}

```
.icons_row {
height:100%;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.icons_cell1, .icons_cell2, .icons_cell3, .icons_cell4 {
height:100%;
width:25%;
display:inline-block;
white-space:normal;
padding-top:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for vertical-align (which aplies to inline elements) is baseline more info here : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

When you add content in you cells, the baseline jumps down with the line-break so the other cells jump down.

To prevent this add `vertical-align:top;`  to `.incon-cell`s so they don't jump down.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/S9XR6/3/)**